# Controlling vector tile zoom

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is there any way to define the {z} variable in the vector tiles portion of the script on the fly based on zoom?  I want to define different numbers for each zoom than the default mapbox {z}:

```
  map.addSource('PWS', {
    type: 'vector',
    tiles: ['//features.mvt?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&apiKey={akey}&tile-size=512&time='+time[0]+'&time='+time[1]+'&time='+time[2]+'&time='+time[3]+'&stepped=true'],
    tileSize: 512,
   });
```

I have tried using this method, and it works OK, but it has a hard time with cached tiles...

```
    map.on('zoomend', function() {
    zm = map.getZoom();
    if (zm > 0 && zm < 2){
      zoomM = 4;
    }
    else if (zm >= 2 && zm < 3){
      zoomM = 4;
    }
    else if (zm >= 3 && zm < 4){
      zoomM = 4;
    }
    else if (zm >= 4 && zm < 5){
      zoomM = 4;
    }
    else if (zm >= 5 && zm < 6){
      zoomM = 5;
    }
    else if (zm >= 6 && zm < 7){
      zoomM = 7;
    }
    else if (zm >= 7 && zm < 8){
      zoomM = 8;
    }
    else if (zm >= 8 && zm < 9){
      zoomM = 9;
    }
    else if (zm >= 9 && zm < 10){
      zoomM = 10;
   }
   else if (zm >= 10 && zm < 11){
     zoomM = 11;
   }
   else {
      zoomM = 12;
   }
   console.log(zoomM,zm);
   const source = map.getSource('PWS');
   source.tiles = ['//features.mvt?x={x}&y={y}&z='+zoomM+'&apiKey={akey}&tile-size=512&time='+pwstime[0]+'&time='+pwstime[1]+'&time='+pwstime[2]+'&time='+pwstime[3]+'&stepped=true'];
   map.style.sources['PWS'].reload();
   });
```

There has got to be a better way to do this...

I have also tried this: [Recommended way to switch tile urls in mapbox-gl-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631344/recommended-way-to-switch-tile-urls-in-mapbox-gl-js)
And seen this: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2941

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you can't use transformRequest to change the z on the fly as the tile requests are made?

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/

Comment: How would you do that exactly?  Would you use a regexp to change z?  The documentation isn't the best. I've tried a bunch of things but it's not working.

Comment: The documentation says "A callback run before the Map makes a request for an external URL. The callback can be used to modify the url, set headers, or set the credentials property for cross-origin requests. Expected to return an object with a  url property and optionally  headers and credentials properties.", Then there is an example at the bottom

Comment: transformRequest: (url, resourceType)=> {
    if(resourceType === 'Source' && url.startsWith('http://myHost')) {
      return {
       url: url.replace('http', 'https'),
       headers: { 'my-custom-header': true},
       credentials: 'include'  // Include cookies for cross-origin requests
     }
    }
  }

Comment: Yes I would use a regexp to extract the z then do your transformation and return the new URL